# mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: network, finder, high-sierra, mount, smb

On my ubuntu server i have a few shares that I can access from finder in the style:

```
smb://server.domain/share
```

successfully without having to type in a password.
When I try to mount the server shares from the command line with:

```
mount_smbfs '//share;user:@server.domain/share' /Volumes/share
```

I get

```
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
```

If i mount one of the shares from the finder all others can be mounted from the command line without this error to appear.

I searched the different stackexchange sites and found the following releated questions and links:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1269386/why-cant-i-mount-shares-by-smb-since-high-sierra
- [Why mac smb connect fails with login from cli but works from finder and with guest account?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/256716/why-mac-smb-connect-fails-with-login-from-cli-but-works-from-finder-and-with-gue)
- [SMB connections throws authentication error after upgrading Mac OS X to 10.13](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300400/smb-connections-throws-authentication-error-after-upgrading-mac-os-x-to-10-13)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/367950/secure-way-to-mount-a-password-protected-cifs-share-in-mac
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208209
- [Mac OS Sierra connected to SMB share keeps forgetting permissions at the folder level](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297681/mac-os-sierra-connected-to-smb-share-keeps-forgetting-permissions-at-the-folder?rq=1)

Most of these have a few thousand views and quite a few upvotes. Most interestingly I found two comments where users express the frustration about this issue not being solved in a consistent way.

On the other hands there are lots of downvotes for answers and some of the questions - it seems as this problem is very well known and some enlighted users think it is very clear what to do.

Since this issue is annoying me daily I am daring to ask the question again with the specific context of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6.

I fear that answers of the past do not work in this context any more.

The reasons I am asking the question in the first place is that the SMB connections get "lost" over night. This is a different behavior then on my other systems. The CIFS connection between my Ubuntu machines stay stable over time while Mac OS seems to have some disconnection policy.

*So my issue could either be solve by making the connection stable or re-establishing the connection automatically with a script*

**How can a permanent or automatically-script reconnected SMB connection between a Mac OS High Sierra 10.3.6 client and an Ubuntu/Linux SMB server achieved?**

Comment: I have filed a bug report https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=45788798

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/1269386/why-cant-i-mount-shares-by-smb-since-high-sierra

Answer (score 3):

According to its man page, `mount_smbfs` takes its share point argument in the form:

```
//[domain;][user[:password]@]server[/share]
```

Note the "user[:password]" part -- the colon and password are in the same brackets, indicating that they're optional but if included, they must be included *together*. Essentially, if you include the colon, whatever's after it (up to the "@") will be taken the password. But you have nothing after the colon, so you're explicitly specifying a blank password.

Also, the man page says you should never run `mount_smbfs` directly, but instead use `mount -t smbfs`.

You need to either include the password explicitly, like this:

```
mount -t smbfs '//share;user:password@server.domain/share' /Volumes/share
```

Or leave off both colon and password:

```
mount -t smbfs '//share;user@server.domain/share' /Volumes/share
```

...in which case it'll look for a password in ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf, and if it isn't there it'll prompt for one. I had thought that it could look in the keychain, but apparently it doesn't know how to do that. This means that there is no non-interactive, secure way to supply a password to `mount_smbfs`.

Depending on the context this is running in, you might be able to use the `open` command instead:

```
open 'smb://share;user@server.domain/share'
```

I think this'll need to be running in a user session, and doesn't give you control of the mount point (it'll be auto-created in /Volumes).

Oh, one other thing: the "share;" part of the URL specifies an authentication domain to find the user in. Is that part actually correct? If it is, the `open` command should work interactively.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Having the password on the command line is the insecure version I abandoned many years ago. I do not want to go back to this state. The keychain version is what does not work - please try it out yourself. I'd appreciate if you'd remove your answer since it does not help at all and I do not want many downvoted answers again.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl See update.

Comment: Thx for the update - I'll look into this on another day when the network connection drops again

Comment: Indicating how to include the `domain` in the connection string was the key for me. Thanks!