# terminal cannot navigate shares on Big Sur

Tags: terminal, network

mount a share like this:

```
sudo open smb://user:password@NAS/share
```

navigate to share

```
cd share
```

try to list contents

```
ls
ls: .: Operation not permitted
```

EDIT: clarification thanks to Greg's comment. 'sudo ls' fails as well.
In either case - using `open smb://user:password@NAS/share` or `sudo open smb://user:password@NAS/share` the folder is browseable in the finder but not in terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what user run the `open` command, it was mounted for everyone.  The sudo is a red herring.

To navigate to the share use `cd /Volumes/share`.  You can check the mount point by running the command `mount`.

Now the contents are visible running the `ls` command, subject to the permissions of the user running `ls`.

Comment: still not working. I make a new directory with 'sudo mkdir mountdir' then mounted the share with 'sudo mount_smbfs //me@server/share ./mountdir'. 'sudo cd mountdir' seems to execute without error but i am still in the /Volumes directory. 'sudo ls /Volumes/mountdir' gives 'Operation not permitted'

Comment: when i 'umount mountdir' I get 'umount: mountdir: not currently mounted'

Comment: I can mount the share in Finder just fine. I just cannot navigate it in terminal

Comment: I don't get why you want to use sudo. Each sudo command stands on its own.  E.g. sudo cd mountdir will run as root and goto the mountdir, but when it exits you are back to your username and the cd is all forgotten.  If you really need root access, then do sudo su and then you are running all subsequent commands as root - much less confusing.

Comment: I used sudo because I kept getting 'operation not permitted' and I was thinking it is a permissions problem. But it is more profound than that. I think it's an issue with the way security is implemented.

Comment: mkdir mountdir followed by mount -t smbfs //user:pwd@server mountdir (without any sudo) and then ls mountdir will work if the server is configured correctly.  I assume you are logged in as an administrator on the Mac.  If it doesn't work I would be looking for incompatibilities between Big Sur and your NAS (outside my expertise).
Using open, opens the share in its default app (Finder) and always mounts in /Volumes.

Comment: Does the mount complete? Share should appear in Finder and be the last line from the command mount (without anything more).
If the mount completes but the ls fails then that must be due to permissions that 'user' has on the NAS.

Comment: Have a read of the links here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341631/mount-smbfs-server-rejected-the-connection-authentication-error-on-mac-os-high. Some of them may help.

Comment: thank you Gilby but this is what happens

Comment: mount -t smbfs '//server;user:pass@server/share' /Volumes/mnt
mount_smbfs: mount error: /Volumes/mnt: Operation not permitted
mount: /Volumes/mnt failed with 64

Comment: stefan@Stefans-Air /Volumes % sudo mount -t smbfs '//server;user:pass@server/share' /Volumes/mnt
stefan@Stefans-Air /Volumes % ls
Macintosh HD mnt

Comment: stefan@Stefans-Air /Volumes % cd mnt
cd: permission denied: mnt
stefan@Stefans-Air /Volumes %